# Python Unicode Error 'in' Statement

Tags: python, unicode, decode

So I'm trying to use a check to see if a string is 'in' another string. But, one of the strings has the '™' character which isn't in the default set of unicode characters that python uses. So my code would look like:

```
if string in item.name: '''do something'''
```

Where item.name has the trademark symbol. How can I still check to see if string is in item.name (string could have the trademark symbol as well and I want to check for that). Thanks!

Comment: "which isn't in the default set of unicode characters that python uses" - what makes you say that?

Comment: So whats the problem now?did you have tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

By [using `unicode`s.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

```
>>> u'™' in u'©™®'
True
```

Comment: What if you wanted to check if a whole string was located in another string, the second string having the trademark symbool?

Comment: Why do you think that anything would be different?